# iOS MKMapView shows blank map if initialized in landscape mode while home button is on the right

Tags: ios, mkmapview, landscape

I'm trying to use MKMapView with my Cordova based app, everything seems to work fine except when I initialize it using the code when device is in landscape mode while home button is on the right:

```
MKMapView* mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 62, 824, 708)];
```

The map shows blank with only the 'Legal' wording visible on the corner of the map.
[image: blank map]

The weird thing is when the home button is on the left and still in landscape mode, calling the same code above have no issue showing the map.

And in portrait mode, it works fine every single time...
[image: working map]

Another thing to note is that after initializing it properly in portrait mode, rotating the device to landscape again it will work. Also, it only happens on the iPad 4, iPad mini and iPhone 5 (company devices, not mine) that I have while the iPhone 6 Plus doesn't have this issue. However on the iPhone 6 Plus the coordinates for the map are out when in landscape mode as well, means if I give it a coordinate to center the map, it centers at the wrong place, but when in portrait mode or when home button is on the left it centers correctly! I wonder if these two issues are related..

Is this an iOS bug? Or something to do with Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured out the problem.

It was caused by a combination of..

- Cordova Status Bar plugin -> where status bar is set to be hidden on landscape mode
- iOS 9
- Device is rotated in landscape mode, with Home button on the right
- Wrong calculation of MKMapView bounds, causing it to render outside of device screen

The root of the problem is on the line:

```
MKMapView* mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 62, 824, 708)];
```

If you add 62 with 708, it equals to 770px, while my device is only 768px in height, it renders 2px out of device screen.

4 of these conditions must be met for it to happen.

If the device is not in landscape mode with Home button on the right, or if it is on iOS 8, or if you're not using cordova status bar plugin (or something similar), or the bounds are set correctly, it won't happen.

No wonder I searched on Google and found no one having the similar issue >.<

Hope this information helps someone.. but I doubt so.

At the end I choose to fix my bounds calculation and never let it render outside of device screen, and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like map frame is ok, but map is not rendered.
Setup delegate for mapView in your ViewController:
`mapView.delegate = self;`
And implement these methods where you can check the map:

```
- (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error {
// here you can catch error if map failed
}
- (void)mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
// here you can see when map starts loading
}
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
// here you can see when map finishes loading
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, in portrait mode I verified that mapViewWillStartLoadingMap gets called first and after that mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap gets called before the map shows up. However on the problematic side of landscape mode, none of these functions gets called, including the mapViewDidFailLoadingMap..

Comment: Try another delegate method `- (void)mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView fullyRendered:(BOOL)fullyRendered;`

Comment: only mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap gets called with fullyRendered = YES